# How to get the group by result only if it satisfies where condition for all instances of same value

Tags: mysql

I have a database table similar to these -

Answers Table

```
quiz_id   question_id answer_id user_answer_id
--------------------------------------------------
  2            12          23         23
--------------------------------------------------       
  2            12          34         34
--------------------------------------------------       
  2            13          35         36
--------------------------------------------------     
  2            13          33         33
--------------------------------------------------       
  2            14          28         28
--------------------------------------------------
```

user_quizzes

```
quiz_id assignment_id user_id ....
--------------------------------------------------
2           3           12
--------------------------------------------------
```

I want my query to give me count of question_id of only those for whom 
answer_id = user_answer_id
that is the result should be:-
total
2

Comment: Does your question have two correct answers?

Comment: I think you're lacking normalisation!

Comment: yes  I know its not properly normalized, I am working on someone else's db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery and a `having` clause:

```
select count(*)
from (select a.quiz_id
      from answers a
      group by a.quiz_id
      having sum(answer_id <> user_answer_id) = 0
     ) q;
```

Alternatively, you can rephrase the question:  How many quizzes have only correct answers?  This might lead you to:

```
select count(*)
from quizzes q
where not exists (select 1
                  from answers a
                  where a.quiz_id = q.quiz_id and
                        a.answer_id <> a.user_answer_id
                 );
```

This assumes a table called `quizzes` . . . and also assumes that each quiz has at least one answer.

Comment: Can you explain the use of '<>' operator in your query

Comment: It means not equals.